# start the command line and run a command on the startup

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

is there a way to open a cmd propmpt and run a command automatically when the server starts up or boots up?

I want to run this C:\Design run on bootup

how would I do that

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is a startup script. You would set it in the group or local policy.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/gptext_assigncomputerstartupscripts.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

You could also setup this as a service.  There are many articles on the web to do this.  I had to do this to ensure a share was properly mapped on my Windows server globally.